# IE8 div visible on hover, but vanishes when embedded select has focus

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a `<div>` tag that when the user hovers over it, it displays a hidden form contained within a nested `<div>` tag. The problem is that when the user goes to use the `<select>` tag inside the form, the changed focus(?) causes the browser to lose the hover on the containing `<div>` tag. Not a problem in every browser except our good friend IE, which reverts the nested `<div>` tag to its hidden state.

Here's the JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3qVv7/3/

HTML:

```
<div id="button_box"><h2>Hover This</h2>
    <div id="form_box">
        <form action="#" method="post">
            <select id="select_option" onChange="Javascript:doSomething();">
                <option value="a">Value A</option>
                <option value="a">Value B</option>
                <option value="a">Value C</option>
                <option value="a">Value D</option>
                <option value="a">Value E</option>
            </select>
        </form>               
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#button_box {
     display:block; 
     width: 150px; 
     height: 75px; 
     position:relative; 
     background: #ddd;
}

#button_box h2 {
     text-align: center
}

#button_box #form_box {
     display: none; 
     position:relative; 
     top: 51px; 
     width: 150px; 
     background: #ccc
}

#button_box:hover #form_box {
     display:block
}

#form_box select { 
     background: #bbb 
}​
```

Any suggestions on how I can get a select nested in a hidden div to not kill the hover state?

Comment: Have you tried adding `:hover` to `#form_box` too?  Also, please make your OP more self-contained by adding the code.  Otherwise, when the jsfiddle link goes dead, the question is meaningless.

Comment: I'm experiencing this same problem in Chrome, as well. I have to fidget around and click on the drop-down multiple time for the nested `div` to stay visible.

Comment: I would also suggest manipulating `visibility` for "form_box". You'll have a larger `div` for "button_box", but you shouldn't experience the same problem.

Comment: @Sparky672 - Thanks for the help/tip. Adding :hover to other containers has no affect. It is as if IE interprets the action that if the `select` has focus, the `div` I'm hovering over no longer does.

Comment: @Shabab: Interchanging `display:none` and `visibility:hidden` makes no difference. Thanks tho.

Comment: Maybe [something in here](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) could help.   Also, does your HTML [validate](http://validator.w3.org/)?  IE hates invalid HTML.

Comment: Do you want the select to say visible after you hover or hide when you leave the parent div? Also some of the css is off. The parent div has a height of 75px but the select is down 51px which puts part of it outside of the parent div. One option is to remove the height on the parent or change the select to absolute bottom:0px; might have better control using JQuery to control hover

Answer (score 0):

Your positioning is taking the form box out of the button box. Use `margin-top`, `padding-top` some other method of spacing, rather than `positioning` and `top`. Also, the fixed height on the `#button_box` is making problems.

Essentially, make sure that the thing you want to appear in is still contained inside the element that has the hover styles. You can put the hover on a wrapper div that contains everything, use margins instead of fixed heights and positioning, and other options that will help so long as everything is visually contained.

Here's a pen to use as an example:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cbwEq